# Does ILOM on recent Sun rackmount servers fully support Linux?

Tags: linux, sun, lom

Do the recent Sun rackmount servers with ILOM fully support installation of Linux (Ubuntu or Fedora maybe) via the ILOM (connected by ssh) without having to hook up a display, kbd, and mouse?

I have an old Sun v20z right now that will install Solaris no problem over the Service Processor but when trying to install Ubuntu 9 64-bit server I get one line on the console then it goes blank.

I'd be interested in know which if any of the recent x64 models would allow me to install and run linux while completely avoiding any need for external display, keyboard, or mouse.

Thanks!

Comment: Does that version of the ILOM support a web connection with a console redirection?

Comment: No, it doesn't unfortunately :(  Do I just need a Linux distro that has a text installer?  I have installed Solaris this way before.  Does anyone know which distro would work to go thru the installer via the SP in a bash session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recent ones I've used (X4140s, X4170s) fully support this.  You can use a Java client downloaded from the ILOM to redirect the servers virtual CD-ROM drive to a local ISO or disc, and install any of the supported operating systems.

Comment: Everything almost perfect with this java client - except it has the keyboard mappings totally screwed up.